# Preg_replace for /* ... */

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to make a outcomment preg_replace function for my custom template system.

I have tried the following:

```
// Outcomment
$pattern[] = "//*(.*?)/*/is";
$replace[] = "";

$content = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $content);
```

But I am not sure that I quite understand the way that preg_replace work.

I am trying to do so that everything between `/*` and `*/` will be removed.

Comment: You need to escape the delimiters (here `/`) inside your pattern as well as the `*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$str = "Hello my name /* some comment */ is PHP /* and this comment*/ " ;       
$clean = preg_replace("/\/\*(.*?)\*\//", "", $str) ;

echo $clean ; //Outputs Hello my name is PHP
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, even without taking escaping into account, you have `/*` at both ends of the expression, so the one at the end is the wrong way round.

Secondly, both `/` and `*` are special characters for regex, and need to be escaped with a preceding backslash.

So your expression would end up looking like this:

```
"/\/\*(.*?)\*\//is"
```

hope that helps.

Finally, please note that this expression will fail if your comments are allowed be nested -- ie comments within comments. This would make it *much* harder to match.