# PHP regex in no specified string to get a name and phone number which string in array

Tags: php, regex

I poor in regex, But I must solved a problem, I have a problem which string in array as below:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [delivery_name] => Michael +182322085183/+189626742830
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [delivery_name] => RAI
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [delivery_name] => +182165070134
        )
)
```

How to proccess separating and taking to get a name and phone number. I want to result as below:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
           [name] => Michael
           [phone] => +182322085183
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
           [name] => +182165070134
           [phone] => +182165070134
        )
)
```

If not matches a number phone will unset the array.

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Just because you are _poor in regex_ doesn't imply that you shouldn't even make an attempt to solve your problem.  This isn't a _free-coding service_.

Comment: I think you forgot to include the string, test case and output and your tried work

Comment: @devnull you're wrong. it is. unfortunately.

Comment: @AlmaDo Users make it that way.  It depends on _you_.

Comment: @devnull: If you cannot help him, do not talk like that.

Comment: @DaveJackson It seems that not only the OP, but you too need to read help on asking: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @devnull: Try see in your link at statement: Help others reproduce the problem. Not all questions benefit from including code. But if your problem is with code you've written, blablabla....

Comment: @DaveJackson Feel free to post an answer yourself.  If you feel strongly about what I commented, flag it for moderator attention, discuss about it in [chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com) or post a question on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @devnull I just solved the problem. Result at http://ideone.com/Kv6RTY

Comment: @LorenRamly Good.  That shows what one can achieve by _attempting_.  Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 1):

Tell the truth I'm not that good in reg-ex as well. But no worries try stuff, there is plenty of ways to do things.

This is not code but what you need to do, lets take the first array as **array_one** and the resulting array as **array_two**.

1) Iterate each array within **array_one**

2) From what I see here I assume that each entry of **array_one** has only the key value "[delivery_name]" and that "delivery_name" values come as either of these three methods

```
name + numeric value with symbols
name only
numeric value with symbols only
```

3) So split the string first from the space character ( there are functions in php for this )this will devide the name and number. ( Here it is assumed that there is only one name and no multiple names delimited by spaces ).

4) We'll have to populate the resulting array by adding the split string values, to the second array.
Before that we'll have to use `preg_replace` to replace unwanted symbols so that we could get a refined string as a number. ( Ref : [Preg_replace for /* ... */](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920619/preg-replace-for) ).

5) Once that is done do a check using `is_numeric` function for both the string values. If both are non numeric skip adding the data to the second array. If one is not numeric then ad that as the **"name"** key value in the second array and the other as **"phone"**